# Find a row in a dataframe using regex

Tags: r, dataframe, input

I have a translation table (`trans_df`):

```
trans_df <- read.table(text = "rs1065852 rs201377835 rs28371706 rs5030655 rs5030865 rs3892097 rs35742686 rs5030656 rs5030867 rs28371725 rs59421388
                       G           C          G         A         C         C          T        CTT         T          C          C
                       G           C          G         A         C         C        del        CTT         T          C          C
                       A           C          G         A         C         T          T        CTT         T          C          C
                     del         del        del       del       del       del        del        del       del        del        del
                       G           C          G       del         C         C          T        CTT         T          C          C
                       G           C          G         A         C         C          T        CTT         G          C          C
                       G           C          G         A         C         C          T        del         T          C          C
                       A           C          G         A         C         C          T        CTT         T          C          C
                       G           C          A         A         C         C          T        CTT         T          C          C
                       G           C          G         A         C         C          T        CTT         T          C          T
                       G           C          G         A         C         C          T        CTT         T          T          C",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, colClasses = "character")
```

and `input` :

```
    input <- read.table(text = "rs1065852 rs201377835 rs28371706 rs5030655 rs5030865 rs3892097 rs35742686 rs5030656 rs5030867 rs28371725 rs59421388
+ G|A           C        G|A         A         C       T|C          T  CTT         T        C|T          C", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, colClasses = "character")
```

I want to find the input row in the trans_df using regular expression.
I have achieved it by position:

```
Reduce(intersect,lapply(seq(1, ncol(trans_df)), 
                          function(i) {grep(pattern = input[, i], 
                          trans_df[, i])}))
```

Is there any way to do this where pattern = input? Please advise.

Comment: Please make sure that you provide [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) so It is easier to help you.

Comment: @Sotos in this case you have an example and all the data, what is wrong?

Comment: Go through the link I gave you. It needs to be reproducible! i.e. something that we can just copy/paste in our R sessions

Comment: @Sotos give me a second will fix it.

Comment: No problem. Take your time.

Comment: @Sotos, fixed. Please have a look

Comment: So something like this `Map(grep, input, trans_df)` ?

Comment: @Sotos thanks a lot!!!! BRAVO please post as an answer you are genius!!!

Comment: @Sotos will it take into consideration the position or I need to provide the input with same column order like the translation table columns?

Comment: It assumes that the columns match one - on- one. i,e. colA of `trans_df` is colA in `input`...and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Map`to achieve that, i.e.

```
Map(grep, input, trans_df)
```

However, that makes the assumption that your columns match one-on-one. If that does not stand, then you can use `match` to make them the same, i.e.

```
Map(grep, input[match(names(input), names(trans_df))], trans_df)
#or in the same sense and to keep input intact,
Map(grep, input, trans_df[match(names(trans_df), names(input))])
```

However, I think that would beat your purpose though.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `subset()` here and pass it the criteria for a matching row.  In this case, the criteria involves checking each column in the data frame against a set of known values.  Assuming that input is a named vector, we can try the following code:

```
subset(trans_df, rs1065852 == input["rs1065852"] & rs201377835 == input["rs201377835"] &
       ... & rs59421388 == input["rs59421388"])
```

Comment: If rs1065852 = A or G (="A|G") I need to check in the trans_df in this position if it's A or G. How this can be achieved using your solution?

Comment: @Dr.RichardTennen It starts getting ugly now: Use `(rs1065852 == 'A' | rs1065852 == 'G') & <other conditions>` ... but this is already a departure from your question.  Your question implies that you have a vector or maybe data frame of values, one for each column, and you want to extract rows from `trans_df` using that input.